# Localization: general culture vs. specific culture

Tags: c#, localization, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store

I've created a simple windows store application with 3 languages on board: English, German and Russian. I'm not using full culture names like ru-RU, en-US or de-DE, but I'm just specifying the language: ru, en, de. So I have the following resource files structure:

```
prj-folder
\ strings
  \ de
    \ Resource.resw
  \ en
    \ Resource.resw
  \ ru
    \ Resource.resw
```

In the manifest I set the default culture to 'en'. My development workstation has an en-US culture, so if run the app everything is in English (as expected, btw).
To test other cultures I add the following code in `App.ctor`:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

    // ...
}
```

It works well. I can see everything in Russian or German.

I've made the release of my app - today it has appeared in the Store. On the development workstation (en-US) everything works as expected. But! On the workstation with German (de-DE culture) - everything is also in English: description in Windows Store and UI in application. I have no idea what is wrong with my localization and why everything is always in English.

**NOTE: it might be important.** I added German and Russian in the update of the app. The first version had only one language on board - English and the default culture was en-US.

**UPDATE:** seems that the problem is related to the device with German Windows 8. Most of applications are running with de-DE culture, but my app is running under en-US culture. I will try to figure our why.

Comment: Wait for the update to be published to the market and you'll have your languages.

Comment: hm. can you reproduce the behaviour by downloading your own app from the store?

Comment: @linkerro update is already in the store, of course

Comment: @Vlad yes, I made an update on German Windows 8 - English; then I uninstalled app and installed again - again English

Comment: @ie.: well, then you can attach a debugger and look up what is the UI Culture of the threads?

Comment: Sadness. Anyway, the preferred way of testing this out is using the emulator and setting that up with the language of choice. Then you can check if your code is working properly.

Comment: @Vlad unfortunately, I have not dev tools on the German workstation, but I'll try to think something about it

Comment: @ie.: In this case, perhaps you can add some debug output into the program? For example, `Debug.WriteLine`'s output can be caught with sysinternals' [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647). Or you can write it into a file.

Answer (score 2):

Does your manifest list all three languages?  The set of languages used by the application is filtered to the languages present in the manifest, so if your manifest includes only "en", that's what you'll get regardless of user settings.

.NET Culture and UI Culture have no effect on localization of Windows Store apps.  The setting of interest is:

Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages
That's the list used by the resource loader, which is constructed from:

1) Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages  The user language profile as set in the languages

2) Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.ManifestLanguages.  The languages defined in the application manifest.

3) Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride.  Optional application-specific *persistent* primary language.

Simplifying a bit, ApplicationLanguages.Languages is the intersection of the GlobalizationLPreferences.Languages with the ManifestLanguages.  If there's no intersection, the manifest languages win.   Primary language override is always prepended to the list, without being filtered against the manifest.

If other modern apps are showing German, the most likely cause is that you don't have German in the manifest.  Another possibility is that PrimaryLanguageOverride is somehow getting stuck on Engish.